# system.data column 'invariantname' is constrained to be unique

Tags: c#, entity-framework, firebird

I'm using FirebirdSqlProvider 4.8.1.1 and EntityFramework 6.0
I get the exception `system.data column 'invariantname' is constrained to be unique` when I'm trying to use EntityFramework.
My `app.config` file:

```
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="FirebirdSql.Data.EntityFramework6.FbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework.Firebird" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" type="FirebirdSql.Data.EntityFramework6.FbProviderServices, EntityFramework.Firebird" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" />
      <add name="FirebirdClient Data Provider" invariant="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Firebird" type="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FirebirdClientFactory, FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

I have only one DbProviderFactories entity in my `machine.confgi` file.
How to fix it?

Comment: If the error is about `invariantname`, then I would expect the problem to be with the `invariantname`, not about the `invariant`. In other words: you're looking at `<DbProviderFactories>`, but the error suggests you should be looking at `<providers>`.

Comment: Have you also looked at your machine.config?

Comment: Sorry. I was checking 32-bit  version of machine.config file. I had two Firebird ProviderFactories in 64-bit one.

Answer (score 6):

For me there was a duplicate IBM DB2 provider.

I had to navigate to:

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG

And then open the machine.config file and remove the duplicated line.

The 2 lines were:

```
  <add name="IBM DB2 for i .NET Provider" invariant="IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for IBM i" type="IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.iDB2Factory, IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9cdb2ebfb1f93a26"/>
```

Comment: It worked but in my case machine.config is present in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config